# Reference JSON object

Tags: json

Okay.. I know this question might be a bit silly. But I was trying out accessing nodes within JSON in JavaScript context.

The following doesn't work:

```
{foo : 1000, bar : 2000, car : 3000}.foo
{foo : 1000, bar : 2000, car : 3000}['foo']
// Both give me the following error
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

However, if I assign JSON to a variable and reference from there, it works properly.

```
var demo = {foo : 1000, bar : 2000, car : 3000};
demo.foo;
// Output: 1000
```

I think variable `demo` and JSON expression above should be the same thing, but why syntactically only the latter works?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Well, it does work, in the first case you are declaring object and pulling foo value from it, but not passing it to anything.
Try console.log({foo : 1000, bar : 2000, car : 3000}.foo), or do const foo = {...}.foo.
The syntax error you are getting is from creating object, but not passing it to anything

Comment: @noitse Thank you very much. It works. Also `var temp = {foo : 1000, bar : 2000, car : 3000}.foo; temp;` works.